# Are there any Jewish or Hebrew traditions that hold that the Passover and the binding of Isaac were on the same day (15 Nisan)?

Tags: passover, binding-of-isaac

Are there any Jewish or Hebrew traditions  that hold  that the Passover and the binding of Isaac were on the same day (15 Nisan)?

I answered this question on Christianity SE ([Had the Catholic Church a tradition of commemorating Abraham's sacrifice?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/65987/had-the-catholic-church-a-tradition-of-commemorating-abrahams-sacrifice)) and it got me to see if I could find a Jewish traditions that holds that Abraham's sacrifice occurred on the same day that Moses lead the Hebrew people out of bondage?

Does anyone know of any possible Jewish traditions on this line of thinking and their respected sources? I have been unable to find any.

I have always been interested in religious traditions and I  mean no offence in asking this question, even though I be a gentile.

Related: [Date of the Akeida?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94812/date-of-the-akeida) This question is not asking about a Binding of Isaac and 15 of Nisan tradition.

Comment: I don't believe so. IIRC, the standard Jewish tradition is that the binding of Isaac took place on Rosh Hashana.

Comment: Standard tradition puts the akedah at Rosh HaShannah which is the beginning of the Jewish Calendar's New Year. This year it falls out on Sept. 11.  I agree with RM's comment. I do not find anyone who says it was specifically Passover, but I don't know everything LOL. :)

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Although we read the Akeidah in the Torah reading on the second day of Rosh Hashanah, I have been unable to track down a source that says the event actually took place on Rosh Hashanah. Maybe I'm just blind, and don't see the obvious source. Could you point it out to me?

Comment: @DavidKenner See my above comment.

Comment: Close voters: Please note that my question was posted prior to this question: [Date of the Akeida?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94812/date-of-the-akeida) I am asking about traditions of a different date.

Comment: @KenGraham As noted in the comments to your post on meta, that question is a bit broader than yours, asking for dates in general rather than a very particular date. As any complete answer to that question will list the various traditions regarding when the Binding of Isaac was, it will automatically answer yours either in the affirmative or the negative. As such, even though yours was posted first, that question is probably the better one to keep open. Unless I’m missing something about your question - are you asking something more than if the Binding occurred on Passover?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the sources that I quoted in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/94815/13438), a commentary by [R. Yitzchak Meir Alter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Meir_Alter), indeed asserts that the Binding of Isaac took place on the first day of Passover, 15 Nissan. Below is the original Hebrew text in which he wrote this:

**Chiddushei HaRim Al HaTorah, Parshat Vayeira**

> **יצחק אבינו ע"ה נעקד בפסח** ונעקדו עמו כל נשמות ישראל ונטהרו וזכו לקשר
>   השבע מדות אל הקדושה בקשר אמיץ בכח העקידה וזהו וישב אברהם בבאר שבע
>   היינו שבע המדות הקדושות ובכח **העקידה שהיתה ביום ט"ו בניסן** הי' לו ולזרעו
>   אחריו כח קדוש לתקן את השבע דמדות במצות ספירת העומר שהוא שבע שבתות

The parts that I bolded are where he says, respectively:

> Isaac our father, peace be unto him, was bound on Passover.

And:

> The Binding, which was on the 15th day of Nissan

It should be noted, though, that this is a rather late source, and does not cite any earlier sources for its claim. The more mainstream view, as I cited in the above mentioned answer, appears to be that the Binding occurred on [Rosh Hashana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosh_Hashanah) (1st of Tishrei) or [Yom Kippur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Kippur) (10th of Tishrei).

It is possible that R. Alter was basing his claim on a passage from [Exodus Rabba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exodus_Rabbah) which states in reference to the month of Nissan:

**Exodus Rabba Parsha 15**

> ובו נולד יצחק ובו נעקד
>
> And in it Isaac was born, and in it he was bound

Indeed, [R. David Luria](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90) explicitly cites this passage as saying that the Binding occurred on Passover:

**Beiur Radal L'Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer 31:44**

> אבל באגדה דשמות פט"ו אמרו שהעקדה היה בפסח עיין שם
>
> But in the Agadah of Shemot Parsha 15, they said that the Binding was
>   on Passover; see there.