# Date of the Akeida?

Tags: history, calendar, vayera, binding-of-isaac

Are there sources in our tradition which discuss the Hebrew date of Akeidas Yitzchak? The fact that we read the Akeida on Rosh Hashana or, properly, every day suggests to me that the "real" date is unknown in our mesorah. How could such a significant date have been forgotten? Or, put another way: We know the date of the Creation of the world. Why don't we know the date of the Akeida?

Related:[Are there any Jewish or Hebrew traditions that hold that the Passover and the binding of Isaac were on the same day (14 Nisan)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94810/are-there-any-jewish-or-hebrew-traditions-that-hold-that-the-passover-and-the-bi)

Comment: actually many say it was on Rosh HaShannah and therefore Sarah Imeinu's yahrtzeit is also Rosh HaShannah. I do not think absolutely everyone agrees. I don't remember a solid source offhand, but since Rashi brings the Medrash that Sarah was niftar because her heart went out during the akedah (she thought Yitzchak died), the two dates are held to be the same.

Comment: For the record, the date of the creation of the world is also a matter of dispute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[R. Yehuda Ayash](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%99%D7%90%D7%A9) points out that there are contradictory passages in the [Zohar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zohar). In [Parshat Vayikra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vayikra_(parsha)) it says that the Binding of Isaac took place on [Rosh Hashanah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosh_Hashanah), while in [Parshat Vayeitzei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vayetze) it implies that it took place on [Yom Kippur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yom_Kippur). He says that further analysis is required to reconcile the two passages:

**[Mateh Yehuda O.C. 584:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7930&st=&pgnum=75)**

> קורין וה' פקד וכו' כתב הר"ן ז"ל הטעם לפי ששתיהן נפקדו בר"ה ומה שקורין
>   בשני פרשת העקידה פירש הר"ן ז"ל כדי להזכיר ענין עקידת יצחק ואילו שבשביל
>   כך תוקעין בשופר של איל ע"כ ועדיפא מינה הי"ל להר"ן ז"ל לומר שביום ר"ה
>   נעקד יצחק כדאיתא בזוהר פרשת ויקרא דף י"ח וז"ל בהאי יומא יצחק אתעקד
>   ועקיד כולא ושרה מיללת וקול שופרא תקיף לחדא זכה חולקיה מאן דעבר בינייהו
>   ואשתזיב מנייהו אמ"ר אבא בגין כך קרינן פרשתא דיצחק בהאי יומא דבהאי יומא
>   אתעקד יצחק לתתא ואתקשר בההוא דלעילא אימתי אתקשר בשעתא דכתיב ויעקוד את
>   יצחק בנו וגו' ע"כ ושוב אחר כותבי מצאתי בספר חמדת ימים שכתב דאמרו רז"ל
>   שנעקד יצחק ביוה"כ לעת ערב כדאיתא בזוהר פרשת ויצא דההיא שעתא דאתעקד
>   יצחק ע"ג מרבחא בין הערבים הוה וביארו בפרקי ר"א שהיה ביוה"כ ע"כ וצריך
>   עיון לזווג שני המאמרים כאחד כי לפי הנראה דסברות חלוקים הם וראיתי
>   להמפרש בעל באר יצחק בפרשת וירא דרוש ד' שנרגש מזה והניחו בצ"ע יע"ש

[R. Chaim Yosef Dovid Azulai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Yosef_David_Azulai) quotes R. Ayash's contradiction, and says that it's not a question at all because the passage in Parshat Vayikra is not to be understood literally:

**[Machzik Beracha O.C. 584:2 (Kuntras Acharon)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9191&st=&pgnum=270&hilite=)**

> והרב מהר"י עייאש בדין זה הקשה ב' מאמרי הזהר דנראין סותרין ע"ש ולק"מ כי
>   מאמר פ' ויקר' אין הדברי' כפשטן כי הוא רומז על הארש בסתא עליון עלה
>   בכב"ש המד"ות שבמקדש הרומזים לאבות כידוע

R. Ayash's question and R. Azulai's answer are also cited by [R. Yaakov Chaim Sofer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Chaim_Sofer) in [Kaf Hachaim 582:16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14425&st=&pgnum=24&hilite=).

The identification of the date as Rosh Hashana is also made in the [Pesikta Rabbati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesikta_Rabbati):

**[Piska 40](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39324&st=&pgnum=371)**

> ויקרא אברהם את שם המקום [ההוא] ה' יראה אשר יאמר היום [וגו'] מהו היום
>   כהיום מפני שר"ה היה

I have also seen various later sources cite the [Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirke_De-Rabbi_Eliezer) (perhaps Chater 32) as the source that it occurred on Yom Kippur, but I have been unable to find it there.

[R. Ytzchak Meir Alter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Meir_Alter) writes that the Binding of Isaac occurred on Passover, though he gives no source for this:

**Chiddushei HaRim Al HaTorah, Parshat Vayeira**

> יצחק אבינו ע"ה נעקד בפסח

However, in [Exodus Rabba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exodus_Rabbah) there is a passage which states that the binding of Isaac took place in the month of [Nissan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nisan):

**Exodus Rabba Parsha 15**

> ובו נולד יצחק ובו נעקד
>
> And in it Isaac was born, and in it he was bound.

(The passage had been talking about the month of Nissan.)

Interestingly, [R. Dovid Luria](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90) explicitly cites this [Midrash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midrash)ic passage as saying that the Binding took place on Passover (i.e. even though the passage only mentions the month), so perhaps this was the source of R. Alter's statement as well:

**Beiur Radal L'Pirkei D'Rabbi Eliezer 31:44**

> אבל באגדה דשמות פט"ו אמרו שהעקדה היה בפסח עיין שם
>
> But in the Agadah of Shemot Parsha 15, they said that the Binding was
>   on Passover; see there.

Comment: Great answer. Can you please summarize in the beginning that that's a Nחלוקת and there are 3-4-5-6 possible dates and then present each one with its sources to streamline the answer for easy reading.